# gulp map of source file and its destination path

Tags: path, gulp, yaml

Is it possible to have something like a map of source files and it's destination path.

config.yml something like

```
entries:    
- source:"node_modules/jquery2/dist/jquery.js"
  destination: "jquery/2/jquery.js"
- source: "node_modules/jquery3/dist/jquery.js"
  destination: "jquery/3/jquery.js"
```

and than gulp task like this

```
function javascripts() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.javascripts)
    //.pipe($.debug({title: 'dest'}))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uglify()
      .on('error', e => { console.log(e); })
    ))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe($.rename(function (path) {
      path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('src/assets/', '');
    }))
    /*.pipe(gulp.dest( function(file) {
      echo file.dirname;
      //var path = file.base.replace('src/assets/js/', '');
      return ($.if(PRODUCTION, PATHS.production , PATHS.staging  ))
    }))*/
    //.pipe($.flatten({ includeParents: 3} ))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION,
      gulp.dest(PATHS.production),
      gulp.dest(PATHS.staging)
    ));
}
```

We need to create something like CDN of script versions.

Comment: So you are starting with 'entries' and wish to run them through javascripts() task/function?

Comment: Yes, we'd like to create an assets repository.